# $_POST with stripped html

Tags: codeigniter, post, pyrocms

I'm using pyrocms on my local machine and i try to submit some html in my post-data to a custom module controller.
i use the CKEditor for adding some content.

i use jquery.post, just for some testing:

```
$('#ticket-form').submit(function(){
    console.warn(CKEDITOR.instances.message.getData());
    $.post("admin/tickets/playground", { message: CKEDITOR.instances.message.getData() } );
    return false;
});
```

I hit the submit button and the console says:

```
<span style="font-size:14px;">Test</span>
```

Looks good.

On the backend side my controller looks like:

```
public function playground(){
    log_message('error',$_POST['message']);
    var_dump($_POST);
}
```

The result of both dumps are:

```
<span >Test</span>
```

There is nothing else in my controller. No html-stripping etc...

pyrocms has a blog module and if i post a blog-post the html won't get stripped.
So the value of CKEditor is fine and the Data i'm posting also. i use no xss etc...

Comment: The input class automatically filters the GET/POST/COOKIE arrays. [Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html)

Comment: it works with other modules (like blog or pages), so it seems that there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

In the constructor of your controller?

Comment: Sorry there was a typo. Should be FALSE;